# format string by custom pattern in java

Tags: java, apache-commons

I have a `String` instance contains numbers such as `1548258598784165`.
I want have a flexible utility for formatting this string to another string.
My goal is following result(for sample):

- rule 1 : **Three star at middle-Four right digit-Four left digit**. result will be : `1548***4165`
- rule 2 : **A dash character instead of any character except three first digit and tow last digit**. result will be : `154-----------65`
- rule 3 : **Split by a space for any four digit**. result will be : `1548 2585 9878 4165`

above rules are sample of my rules for formatting raw string.
My question is : Is there an benefit utility for my goal? I don't want manipulation by `substring` and similar ways.

Comment: Have you considered creating a class to do this for you? You have the rules defined, it shouldn't be too difficult to create a class wrapped around a string that will output these different cases.

Comment: You can convert the string to a char array and then just replace characters by their index (`char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();`), but not sure why you don't want to just use `substring` or "similar ways". What do you expect this "benefit utility" to look like?

Comment: @ZachL because using `substring` for this problem generate very not readable code, several `if` statement, several `NullPointerException` maby throws and ...

Comment: @MJM I don't think there's gonna be a super-relevant library to do this stuff for you. Take the advice in answers below and contain this complexity its its own Class(s). With some effort, I'm sure you could refactor Elliotts answer to be quite readable and elegant.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this follows your requirements

```
public static String customFormat(String in, int i) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (in != null) {
        char[] arr = in.toCharArray();
        switch (i) {
        case 1:
            for (int t = 0; t < 4; t++) {
                sb.append(arr[t]);
            }
            sb.append("***");
            for (int t = arr.length - 4; t < arr.length; t++) {
                sb.append(arr[t]);
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            for (int t = 0; t < 3; t++) {
                sb.append(arr[t]);
            }
            for (int t = 3; t < arr.length - 2; t++) {
                sb.append("-");
            }
            for (int t = arr.length - 2; t < arr.length; t++) {
                sb.append(arr[t]);
            }
            break;
        default:
            for (int t = 0; t < arr.length; t++) {
                if (t > 0 && t % 4 == 0) {
                    sb.append(" ");
                }
                sb.append(arr[t]);
            }
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        System.out.println(customFormat("1548258598784165", i));
    }
}
```

And when run it outputs

```
1548***4165
154-----------65
1548 2585 9878 4165
```

Comment: I'd probably create an Enum with nice names for each format so you don't have a magic number variable `i`

Answer (score 1):

If you want this to be written in a quite elegant way, I believe it is a good idea to create a new class, which will contain a String and methods to operate on that string the way you want. The String could be passed as a paramether to Class' constructor (and then be private inside the class).

Of course, you may just create a class containing the methods to work on a String passed to the method as a paramether, and this would probably be a more universal way (as you may work on normal Strings and not only objects of your own type.)

The methods in both cases may base on standard String-class methods. You can access single signs from your String using `inputString.charAt(int index)`, which appear to be an easy solution for most of your requirements. Every method could return a new String built using chars from the source String and other signs you want it to contain. The only thing you would need to implement is a wrap around the String-class methods.